# Cannot install Vmware Tools on VM PLayer

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, vmware

I have installed Ubuntu 16.10 on VMPlayer 6.0.1 running on Windows 7 Professional, 64-bit 6.1.7601, Service Pack 1.

I go to Player > Manage > Install VMware tools and get the message

```
VMware Tools installation cannot be started manually while the easy install is in progress.
```

I follow all of the solutions at https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1017687  but it makes no difference.

I downloaded the installer from https://packages.vmware.com/tools/esx/latest/windows/x64/index.html and tried to install VMwae tools outside VMplayer.  I just got the message that it should be installed inside VMPlayer (which it won't let me do) and then the installation program ends.

Comment: There reason your using such an old version of VMWare Player?

Answer (score 1):

Edit the virtual machine settings and look for the existence of a `autoinst.flp` and `autoinst.iso` Floppy and/or CD/DVD Drive. Do this with the VM stopped.

If those exist, remove the devices manually. The virtual machine then should be out of the "Easy Install" phase and you'll be able to start the vmware tools install.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it was because of  my using an old version of VMWare Player.  I replaced it with VMware WorkStation 12 Player and was then able to install the VMware Tools.  Thanks,